# Anybody know what she say in this song?

Tags: translation

I don't understand what she say at 0:38

http://www.allocine.fr/video/player_gen_cmedia=19551143&cfilm=145804.html

Anybody know? 
It's not the mandarin language, am i right?

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like a dialect of the Chinese language. I think she's singing "驕妹子，驕妹子驕", "細(小)妹子，細(小)妹子細(小)"，which can be translated literally to "proud girl, proud girl proud" "little girl, little girl little"